# Помогите сделать проверку на размер файла до 1мб

Tags: php, fileupload, img

Нужно сделать проверку загрузки картинки до 1мб не могу чет понять как проверить

```
$unikod = md5(generateCode(32));
    $uploaddir = '../residents/'; 
    $file = $unikod.".jpg"; 
    $filenew = $uploaddir . $unikod.".jpg"; 

    $ext = substr($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'],strpos($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'],'.'),strlen($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])-1); 
    $filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png','.JPG','.BMP','.GIF','.PNG','.jpeg','.JPEG');
    $filesize = filesize($_FILES['upload_image']['tmp_name']);

    if(!in_array($ext,$filetypes)){
        echo "<p>Данный формат файлов не поддерживается ".$filesize."</p>";
    }
    else{ 
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $filenew)) { 
          echo $file."".$filesize; 
        } else {
            echo "error ".$filesize."";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Все у Вас проверяется `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $filenew)) ` В чем вопрос?

Comment: в массиве  $_FILES  есть размер - $_FILES['somefile']['size'], доки хоть раз прочитайте http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($filesize > 1024 * 1024){
    echo "<p>Файл превышает размер 1 МБ</p>";
}
```

Ещё можно настроить в *php.ini* не принимать файлы более 1 мб.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто ограничить размер файла на уровне php.ini и вывести подсказку что нельзя загружать фаил больше одного мегабайта

В php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 1M
```

Если конечно вам ненадо где то ещё на сайте загружать файлы большого размера.